# I want to delete one user in my project in asp.net .but this give me error about ( throw; ).how can do it?

Tags: c#

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Guid code;
        porsemanDBEntities db = new porsemanDBEntities();
        TblUserinfo lst = new TblUserinfo();
        if (e.CommandName == "Hazf")
        {
            GridView1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            code = Guid.Parse(GridView1.SelectedDataKey[0].ToString ());
            ViewState["code"] = code;
            lst = UserInfological.selectitem(code);
            Literalmessage.Text = "آیا برای حذف سوال مطمئن  هستید";
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message _exactly_?

Answer (score 1):

The `throw;` line is inside a `catch` block. That means your code in the `try` block threw an exception. It was caught, but the `throw;` threw the exception further up (effectively counteracting the point of putting a `catch` block in the first place)

Change this line:

```
catch (Exception)
```

to this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

Put a breakpoint on the `throw;`. Execute your code again. Once the breakpoint is hit, you can hover over the `ex` that you added to look at the exception that is thrown.

Based on the exception, you can understand why your code in the `try` block is throwing an exception.